# Should I be using classes for something simple like solving math problems?

Tags: oop

This is a question about using an object-oriented language. I've been using C++ to solve Project Euler for a while, and I recently read in an article that a lot of people treat C++ like a procedural language, since you can get away without creating classes. I've been doing exactly that.

My question is whether it's "bad" to just be writing functions in an object-oriented language`int mult_order(int base, int mod)` for multiplicative order, `gcd(int a, int b)` for gcd, but without putting them in a class). I've been "reinventing the wheel" a lot for the purpose of learning--should I put them in a library, or create a `Math` class or something along those lines?

Comment: There's no correct answer to this question. Some people put these functions in a `Math` class, others use free functions (and perhaps group them together in a namespace to eliminate possible naming conflicts). There's really no "correct" approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I've been taught (and what I've experienced), the underlying idea behind OOP is a simple one:

**Use it when it makes your life easier.**

It could easily be the case that, for your purpose, using a class wouldn't make things easier - you don't have a reason to repeatedly access a single object that performs these mathematical operations - or creating a class would create unnecessary overhead.

For your example, I think you'll be fine without objects, but do consider that somewhere in the future, it may be necessary to create an object that can handle those operations.

Comment: Agreed. As always, look at it as a "right tool for the right job" problem.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need to be using a `namespace` instead of a `class`.

There's nothing wrong with having functions that don't belong to a class, but you should still group them together.

Use a class when you need properties for an object, or inheritance, or state, not just so you can group functions together.

Answer (score 0):

The main benefit using classes is going to give you is reuse through inheritance. So if you find you have situations where you have some common code, and then other sections of code that  are variations on that, then making classes would help you. If not, then you are probably OK the way you are. Not every problem has to be solved with object oriented programming.